# Dart - How do I call a method of a generic type in an abstract class

Tags: dart

I don't even know how to ask this question properly.

First, I have two abstract classes

```
abstract class Syncable<T> {

  int id;
  DateTime dateCreated;
  DateTime dateUpdated;
  DateTime dateExpired;

  Syncable({this.id, this.dateCreated, this.dateUpdated, this.dateExpired});

  T fromJson(dynamic json);
}
```

```
abstract class SyncableTable<M extends Syncable> {

  Future<Database> db;

  SyncableTable(this.db);

  String get tableName;

  /// Simply retrieves a single row by primary id.
  Future<M> getById(int id) async {
    List<Map> list = await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE id = ?", [id]);
    if (list != null && list.length > 0) {
      // *******************************************************
      // THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK
      // Is it possible to use the fromJson() method from M (Syncable)
      return M.fromJson(list.first);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Syncable is extended by my models, and SyncableTable is extended by my classes that describe my tables.

For example:

```
class Pet extends Syncable<Pet> {
  String name;

  Pet({
    this.name,
    int id,
    DateTime dateCreated,
    DateTime dateUpdated,
    DateTime dateExpired,
  }) : super(id, dateCreated, dateUpdated, dateExpired)

  @override
  Exercise fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return Pet(name: json["name"],
               id: json["id"],
               dateCreated: json["dateCreated"],
               dateUpdated: json["dateUpdated"],
               dateExpired: json["dateExpired"]
    );
  }
}
```

```
class PetsTable extends SyncableTable<Pet> {

  @override
  String get tableName => "pets";

  // any other queries/inserts/updates custom to pets table...
}
```

My goal is to be able to do this:

```
PetsTable petsTable = new PetsTable(db);
Pet pet = petsTable.getById(1);
```

I can't achieve this because in SyncableTable class I cannot call the fromJson() method from the generic extending Syncable.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> // Is it possible to use the fromJson() method from M (Syncable)
> return M.fromJson(list.first);
> ```

This won't work because, as written, `fromJson` is an *instance* method on `Syncable`.  If you had an instance of `M`, you could call `fromJson` on that object rather than on the type.

That raises a question: should `fromJson` be an instance method?  Based on the implementation in `Pet`, it would make more sense as a `static` (class) method.  However, changing it to a `static` method won't help your situation because Dart does not treat `static` methods as part of the class interface, so even though `SyncableTable` requires that `M extends Syncable`, it can't guarantee that `M` implements a `fromJson` `static` method.

I don't know of a good way to dispatch `static` or freestanding functions based on type.  An ugly hack would be to make your own map from types to `fromJson` implementations:

```dart
  Future<M> getById(int id) async {
    ...
    if (list != null && list.length > 0) {
      return fromJson[M](list.first) as M;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  typedef FromJsonFunction = dynamic Function(dynamic json);
  final fromJson = <Type, FromJsonFunction>{
    Pet: (json) => Pet(name: json["name"], ...),
  };
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I understand why in the current design it can't and won't work. Il continue looking for an alternative design, if not Il try out some hacks. Thanks though!